# Substitution variable in SQL server

Tags: python, sql-server

It seems when using SQLDeveloper by oracle, I am asked to substitute some values, as it asks me to 'Enter a Substitution Variable'. However, I can get rid of this by just pressing ok.

But in code, calling from python, using pymmsql, it hangs, hence the whole query fails.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this issue?

BTW this issue is occurring on the word 'resorts' so no escape issue

An example query is:

```
SELECT id
FROM holiday_experience
WHERE company_name IN (' Starwood Hotels',
                       'Starwood Hotels Corp',
                       'Starwood Hotels',
                       'Starwood Hotels (Boston Park Plaza)',
                       'Starwood Hotels Corporation',
                       'Starwood Hotels (Sheraton Parsippany Hotel)',
                       'Starwood Hotels International',
                       'Starwood Hotels Inc',
                       'Starwood Hotels, Inc',
                       'STARWOOD HOTELS & RESORTS INTERNATIONAL',
                       'Starwood Hotels and Resorts, Inc',
                       'Starwood Hotels& Resorts',
                       'Starwood Hotels and Resorts',
                       'Starwood Hotels & Resorts (Formerly Westin Hotels)',
                       'Starwood Hotels & Resorts Asia Pacific',
                       'Starwood Hotels & Resorts, Inc.',
                       'Starwood Hotels and Resorts, Inc.',
                       'Starwood Hotels&Resorts',
                       'Starwood Hotels & Resorts',
                       'Starwood Hotels & Resorts Ltd',
                       'STARWOOD HOTELS AND RESORTS NA',
                       'Starwood Hotels & Resorts, Inc',
                       'Starwood Hotels & Resorts Inc',
                       'Starwood Hotels and Resorts Worldwide Inc.',
                       'Starwood Hotels and Resorts Worldwide, Inc.',
                       'Starwood Hotels & Resorts Worldwide Inc.',
                       'STARWOOD HOTELS & RESORTS WORLDWIDE, INC',
                       'STARWOOD HOTELS & RESORTS WORLDWIDE',
                       'Starwood Hotels & Resorts, Worldwide, Inc',
                       'STARWOOD HOTELS & RESORTS, WORLDWIDE',
                       'Starwood Hotels and Resorts World Wide',
                       'Starwood  Hotels and Resorts Worldwide',
                       'Starwood Hotels & Resorts Worldwide Inc',
                       'Starwood Hotels & Resorts Worldwide (Aquent)',
                       'Starwood Hotels and Resorts Worldwide Inc',
                       'Starwood Hotels and Resorts Worldwide, Inc',
                       'Starwood Hotels & Resorts Worldwide, Inc.',
                       'Starwood Hotels and Resorts Worldwide')
```

Comment: What are you sending?  Are you calling a stored procedure, function, etc.?  Do they require parameters?  Can you show us your SQL?

Comment: @TTeeple added as requested :)

Comment: probably the `&Resorts` (no space between `&` and `Resort`) is detected by SQLDeveloper as a "prompt for this value", and is just some plaintext as far as any other SQL library is concerned. You've got at least 1 of those no-space versions near the middle of that param list.

Comment: @MarcB Thank you, that does make sense. The prompt does come up around 8 times though. Is there a way of ignoring a prompt?

Comment: Probably by escaping the `&`? Never used oracle before, but `\&` or whatever the oracle-specific version would be should do the trick.

Comment: @MarcB Escaping still causes the issue but thank you for suggesting it!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling  "set define off;" before running the query